# How to programmatically get the "custom URL" from a category

Tags: magento-1.9

I get my category by ID:

```
$catid = 446;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);
```

And I need to get the "custom URL"

[image]

Is there a function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try by following way :)

```
$catid = 446;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);
$customURL = $category->getData('custom_url'); //replace your attribute code
```

Comment: ah, you're correct, but in this case, it is "umm_cat_target" not "custom_url" ;)

Comment: I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: "custom_url" is just an example. You have to replace it with your attribute code.